# Nodejs, how to display and update text on the same line, like a running clock or download speed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console

In nodejs, how do I display and update text on the same line, like a running clock or currrent download speed?

Answer (score 1):

```js
'use strict';

const rl = require('readline');

function clearLine() {
  rl.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
  rl.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
}

setInterval(() => {
  clearLine();
  process.stdout.write(new Date().toString());
}, 1000);
```